# set soapclient HTTP_METHOD

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Im trying to consume a webserivce usnig soapclient.
The instructions for the connection is to use:

```
request method = "POST";
request ContentType = "application/soap+xml";
```

This is the code im using to create the client

```
 public function init_client(){
     if( $this->env == 'dev'){
         $api_url = self::$test_url;
     }else{
         $api_url = self::$production_url;
     }

     try{
         $options =     array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
         );
         $this->client = new SoapClient( $api_url , $options );


         return true;

     }catch(Exception $e){

         return $e->getMessage();
     }
 }
```

How can i set the client's method and content type ?

Comment: It's not required in PHP's `SoapClient` to specify http method and content-type.  SOAP requests by default use `POST` http method.  You can verify by inspecting the request headers with `$this->client->__getLastRequestHeaders()` after making a call.